# What is the probability density function of a parallelogram

Tags: variance, density-function

A very short question: What would be the probability density function of a parallelogram?

Could we consider it as a two triangular distribution (in pink) that behaves the same and a uniform distribution (blue)?

[image: example diagram]

what would be the PDF of this geometrical shape in this case? and how would the PDF formula change if we skew the parallelogram to the left or right?

and what would be the variance in this case?

My intended experiment is the following:

I want to apply a shear transformation to this parallelogram toward the positive and negative directions, and compute the variance of the distribution at every step. For example, what would be the variance profile if the shear value was $V_{x} \in [-100,100]$?

Below is how the parallelogram looks like with different shear. The area is the same but the opposite side increase/decrease is size.

[image]

I am expecting the variance to look like this in this red curve:

[image]

Below is the PDF that I used, which is not giving me the right results:

$$ f(x)\gets \begin{array}{rcl}
2x & \longrightarrow & 0 < x < V_{x}  \\
0 & \longrightarrow & otherwise   \end{array}
$$

I would like to know what will be the PDF for this parallelogram if I want to apply a shear transformation to it.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sami. Welcome to Cross Validated. The question posed is not related with geometric distribution, a discrete distribution. So, you can remove that tag.

Comment: @User1865345 fixed. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what the random experiment is and the resulting random variable?

Comment: @cdalitz I edited my question to include the experiment I am intended to run and the output of the random variables. Hope this help. I would appreciated your suggestion!

Comment: *"the probability density function of a parallelogram"** What does this mean? Could you explain in what way you consider this. Before we think about the PDF of a parallelogram, we need to know how parallelograms can even have a PDF.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Empiricus I am just trying to describe the shape of the distribution. I have seen many examples of PDFs for trapezoid, and triangular distribution, but not for the type of distribution I am dealing with. Is it possible to have a PDF for this kind of distribution? I kind of stuck for days

Comment: What is random about your shear transformation? Is the shear value $V_s$ a random variable? What is its distribution? And what is the random value you are interested in? This seems to be a use case for Gauss' law of error propagation.

Comment: Geometrical shapes don't have PDFs, nor do they uniquely determine any kind of probability distribution.  This makes it impossible to know and difficult even to guess what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @Sami That would be the same as asking for the star-shape, or the full-circle probability distribution functions. These don't/can't exist, because they violate [what a function is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen many examples of PDFs for trapezoid, and triangular distribution

A PDF is a function that is a single *line/function* and not a geometrical figure.

When you interpret PDFs as a geometrical figure then it is the area/surface below this line. This relates to the idea of the [Rieman integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) as computing the area between the curve described by the function and the x-axis.

In your case with the parallelogram it is not the same as the above interpretation and the trapezoid and triangular distribution.